# twitter response: "error 32: Could not authenticate you" from Heroku, but not desktop

Tags: heroku, twitter, clojure

I'm following the instructions from Carin Meier's [How I Start](https://howistart.org/posts/clojure/1) post and having an issue with posting to twitter (like her example) from Heroku. Note that my app does not have a web component, just a worker component.

Testing on my desktop, I'm able to post to twitter and gist.github.com.

But, on Heroku, I always get `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: Twitter responded to request with error 32: Could not authenticate you.`  I *am* able to post to gist.github.com, so it appears to be a twitter-only issue.

I have used `heroku run lein repl` to confirm that my creds look just fine:

```
(reset! my-twitter-creds   (tw-oauth/make-oauth-creds
                              (env :app-consumer-key)
                              (env :app-consumer-secret)
                              (env :user-access-token)
                              (env :user-access-secret)))
```

but a call to:

```
(tw/statuses-user-timeline :oauth-creds @my-twitter-creds
                           :params {:count 1 :screen-name "myname"})
```

Always gives the error 32.

All the code I've created for this is available to browse here: https://github.com/rogerallen/tweegeemee/blob/master/src/tweegeemee/core.clj

My current suspicion is that there is some requirement on Heroku for a twitter Oauth callback URL.  But, since my app does not have a web-worker, I don't want to have to add this (and it isn't mentioned in the post).

Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described, if you can post to twitter using lein run locally with your environment variables - then the only difference should be the environment variables that heroku is using.

Maybe check with `heroku config` or even put some more logging in an watch in the heroku logs to see what it is calling it with.

Comment: Yes, this ended up being pilot error.  I checked & rechecked my env vars via the web, but missed one single character missing. heroku config outputing text allowed me to put the vars next to each other in a file so I could see my mistake.  Thanks, again!